# Spring maven Errors

Tags: spring, maven

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Update the project
First the right click on the Maven project then go to the Maven->Update Project.Update the project
Solve the issue